# Unable to access yii2 active data povider from gridview

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

everyone this is my function that return the data provider to the gridview.

```
public function search($params)
    {



        $query = EventOrganizer::find()
        ->where(['event.approve' => 0])
        ->groupBy(['event.eventID']);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $query ->joinWith(['event', 'organizer']);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

             $query->select(['event.eventID','event.title','event.startDate','event.startTime','event.endDate','event.endTime',
           'event.photo','event.description','event.location','event.approve',
           "GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`organizer`.`name`,\" \", `organizer`.`organizerID`)) AS Name"])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'event.eventID', $this->eventID])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'organizer.organizerID', $this->organizerID]);


        return $dataProvider;

    }
```

The following is part of my code in gridview. When i trying to access data inside the data provider, I couldnt get to access the column which i had using group_concat.

```
 [
      'label'=> 'End Time',
      'attribute' => 'GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`organizer`.`name`,\" \", `organizer`.`organizerID`)) AS Name',

],
```

I was able to access the other data as follow:

```
 [
          'label'=> 'End Date',
          'attribute' => 'event.endDate',

    ],
```

this prove that my data provider contains data, I have try a couple of ways but i still couldn't get to access on it. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try without the ticks ``:  "GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(organizer.name,\" \", organizer.organizerID)) AS Name"

Comment: Also in search model declare the virtual attribute $Name and in Grid use 'attribute' => 'Name'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some operation on DB and show the result on `gridview`, you must first define a variable on your model and use that on your `gridview`. It's not correct to use SQL query in `gridview`. The long story short, you can easily define a variable and a `getter` method in your model like this:

```
<?php

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class YourModel extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $organizerName;

    // Some AR Model codes go here!

    public function getOrganizerName()
    {
        /** 
         * Suppose you have a 1-1 relation which is called getOrganization
         * and you retrive your desired data about the organization from
         * that
         */
        return $this->organization->name 
               . ' ('
               . $this->organization->id
               . ')';
    }
}
```

Now you can use `organizerName` attribute in your model:

```
[
      'label'=> 'End Time',
      'attribute' => 'organizerName',

],
```

Note that if you want to do somethings like sorting or adding a search box, you must do some extra works for this field.